# jsp:include making the divs mis-aligned in ie7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, jspinclude

I have a webpage in which I am using 2 jsp:include directives. Basically one is the header and other is the footer. The headers and footers are aligned correctly. But the central body of the main page is aligned to the left side.

This is the code of the page.

### page.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.util.*" %>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/style.css" type="text/css" />
<title>HireZilla</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="../top_and_left.jsp" flush="false"></jsp:include>
    <div id="contenttext" align="center">
        Hello World!!
    </div>
    <jsp:include page="../footer.jsp" flush="false"></jsp:include>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code in the browser. I can see that there are lot of tags lying here and there because of the "jsp:include"s. But i dont know how to remove them.

The div tag with "Hello World" gets aligned in the left most corner of the page after the header and before footer elements. My header("top_and_left.jsp") as the name suggests has an 'L' shape with links in the left side of the page and a banner in the top. I want the div tag to come inside the L. I am able to do this in browsers ie8 and above but not in ie7.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html> 

<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css" /> 
<title>HireZilla</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="page" align="center"> 
    <div id="toppage" align="center"> 
        <div id="date"> 
            <div class="smalltext" style="padding:13px;"><strong>Wed Jul 27 23:14:08 IST 2011</strong></div> 
        </div> 
        <div id="topbar"> 
            --Links in the top right corner--
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div id="header" align="center"> 
        <div class="titletext" id="logo"> 
            <div class="logotext" style="margin:30px">Hire<span class="orangelogotext">Z</span>illa</div> 
        </div> 
        <div id="pagetitle"> 
            <div id="title" class="titletext" align="right" >Welcome to HireZilla!</div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div id="content" align="center"> 
        <div id="menu" align="right"> 
            <div id="linksmenu" align="center"> 
                --Left link panel menu--
            </div> 

        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div id="contenttext" align="center"> 
        Hello World!!
    </div> 


<div id="footer" class="smallgraytext" align="center" style="margin-left:225px" > 
        --Footer goes here--
</div> 


    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This is the contenttext element in my css

```
#contenttext{
width:608px;
background-color:#F7F7F7; 
border-left:solid 1px #999999; border-right:solid 1px #999999; 
border-bottom:solid 1px #999999; border-top:dotted 1px #CCCCCC; 
min-height:360px;
}
```

I am not sure whether I have put the question in the right way. I would be happy to clarify.

I dont want to crowd this page more with the css also. If you can let me know which elements you want to see, I can paste their code here.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's not a JSP problem, but a HTML/CSS problem. JSP is just a HTML/CSS producer. In order to get answers/assistance from the HTML/CSS gurus, you would need to leave the JSP part completely out the picture. Show your HTML/CSS instead. Open the JSP page in webbrowser, rightclick, *View Source* to get the generated HTML and edit your question to include the minimal required HTML snippet to reproduce the problem and paste the minimal required CSS along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including a full html page within the body of another html page.  This is causing all kinds of invalid html.

To fix this, strip all of the extra stuff out of footer.jsp and top_and_left.jsp.  Remove the `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`, etc.  The file should only include the html which you want injected into your body.  This will likely clean up most of your issues.

Comment: I did that. My header and footer now contains just the div tags. Still I am getting the same problem in IE7

Comment: Can you update the posted html to reflect that?  It should be more readable now.

Comment: I have updated the new html. Its actually working when i put the "Hello World" div tag inside the "content" div tag just above it. But since they have to be in different files, I have to put "content" div tag open in top_and_left.jsp and close it by putting an extra </div> in page.jsp. Is that okay??

Comment: As far as best practices go, I'm not sure if that's frowned upon. It will work, because the html is all combined and then sent to the browser.